# What is the right way to get an NSString object from an NSArray, keeping Memory Managment in mind?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

What is the right way to get an NSString object from an NSArray,  keeping Memory Managment in mind.

Suppose I have an array

```
NSArray *myNewArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:.......];
```

Now I want to get an object from this NSArray at index 2.

```
NSString *nameString = [myNewArray objectAtIndex:2]; // is it the right way? how to deal with "nameString" 
                                                     // now regarding memory managment, should I release it ?
```

OR I should first alloc nameString and then assign value to it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *myNewArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:.......];
NSString *nameString = [myNewArray objectAtIndex:2]
[myArray release];
```

That's it, no need to bother any more with it. NSString will be released by environment itself.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [Cocoa Memory Management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) (how many times have I started a post with that sentence?).  In particular

> - You only release or autorelease objects you own.
>
>   - You take ownership of an object if you create it using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you send it a retain message.
>   - You use release or autorelease to relinquish ownership of an object. autorelease just means “send a release message in the future” (specifically: when the used autorelease pool receives a drain message—to understand when this will be, see “Autorelease Pools”).

Does the method `objectAtIndex:` begin with "alloc"?  No.  Does it begin with "new"?  No.  Does it begin with "copy" or "mutableCopy"?  No.  Have you sent `retain` to the returned object? No.

Therefore you do not own `nameString`.  Therefore you must not release or auto release it.

Sorry if the above seems a bit "leading by the nose" but when I first started with Objective-C, I found it useful to pretty much go through all the above in my head in exactly that way, otherwise I tended to get it wrong.  It doesn't take long for it all to become second nature.

Comment: Hay, JeremyP !
Thank you for help, but I was not worrying about the release, I just asked for the right way to get value from my NSArray , like should I first alloc the "nameString" or is it right directly assigning the value to nameString . My aim was avoid to autorelease objects, & was worried weather it would return a new autrelease object or not ?

Thank u so much for ur detailed Answer.

Comment: @Sohail: You don't need to alloc a string first in this case because that would be an entirely different string to the one you get back from the array.  Nor do you need to worry too much about autoreleased objects unless you are doing a lot of processing inside an event.

Comment: Great answer, shed some light for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't totally get the "pointer" concept yet. Your variable nameString is just a pointer. Not a string.

In the line :

```
NSString *nameString = [myNewArray objectAtIndex:2];
```

You just assign the pointer to the actual memory address of the second object of the array. That's all.

If you are about to keep this object alive (even if the array will be deallocted), you better retain that object.

Answer (score 0):

`NSArray *myNewArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:.......];`
and getting value in `NSString` from any of `index` wont affect memory ...no need to allocate here.
The collected `NSString` need not required to be retained until you are passing its ownership to another controller/object.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to allocate or initialize NSString object and after all if you are not allocating any memory then there is no need to release....Only release NSArray objects nothing else....

You are going through right way...

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to release the nameString.You only release when you are using(alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”) .